# FactoryGirl passing 'nil' instead of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I'm starting with Rails and RSpec and having a trouble with FactoryGirl. Basically the object don't receive the attributes.

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :name, :email, :show_name, :company, :identity, :password, :phone, :mobile
    validates_presence_of :name, :show_name, :email, :company, :identity, :password, :phone
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

end
```

spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        name "John Doe"
        email "john@example.org"
        show_name "John Doe"
        company "Company"
        identity "123.456.789-10"
        password "abc123"
        phone "1234-5678"
        mobile "1234-5678"
    end
end
```

Rails Console

```
irb(main):001:0> u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'john@example.org' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`company`, `email`, `identity`, `mobile`, `name`, `password`, `phone`, `show_name`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
Mysql2::Error: Column 'company' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `users` (`company`, `email`, `identity`, `mobile`, `name`, `password`, `phone`, `show_name`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'company' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `users` (`company`, `email`, `identity`, `mobile`, `name`, `password`, `phone`, `show_name`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Someone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you maybe mean to put attr_accessible not attr_accessor

attr_accessible is a rails function to whitelist a field for mass assignment. 
attr_accessor is a ruby function to generate getters and setters which will interfere with things.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `attr_accessor` for attributes that are saved in the database. Active Record generates these accessors for you. By using `attr_accessor` you are overwriting those accessors with ones that don't store the values where Active Record is expecting to find them.